# FFmpeg: Batch convert all audio (mp3) in folder to video (mp4) with album artwork (but it down scales my resolution)

Tags: ffmpeg

I followed this source ([FFmpeg: Batch convert all audio (mp3) in folder to video (mp4) with album artwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902282/ffmpeg-batch-convert-all-audio-mp3-in-folder-to-video-mp4-with-album-artwor)) and it works, but it down scales my album cover from `1425 x 1406` dimension to `400 x 396`.

My **Batch code** is

```
echo off
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -an -vcodec copy "C:\mp4\%%~na.jpg"
  "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -loop 1 -i  "C:\mp4\%%~na.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -vf pad="width=ceil(iw/2)*2:height=ceil(ih/2)*2" -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest "C:\mp4\%%~na.mp4" )
pause
```

**Problem** is I don't know how to fix "down scaling" thing, and I am sorry for stupid questions but I need to know it. I watched other errors or tried to understand codes from others but I am not doing it well.

Comment: Share full log for one execution.

Comment: @Gyan First picture: https://prnt.sc/yv03gn
Second Picture: https://prnt.sc/yv0gmn
Third Picture: https://prnt.sc/yv0i2s
That is for one Mp3 file but it is doing for all of them

Comment: I see no rescaling. The covers in the MP3s are `400x395`.

Comment: Yeah it works. Was not thinking you should change album cover from 400 x 395 dimensions to 1425 x 1406. I thought it would automatically convert input image + mp3 = mp4. Thanks @Gyan :D